# Can MASE be used with a rolling forecast?

Tags: forecasting, model-evaluation, mase

I have four years of monthly data, but I want to use three years to test the forecast of a model which uses only one year of historical data in a rolling way. For example:

- historical data from Jan-2016 to Dec-2016 will be used to forecast Jan-2017 to Dec-2017
- but then Feb-2016 to Jan-2017 data will be used to forecast Feb-2017 to Jan-2018.

Can I still use MASE to test the accuracy of this forecast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rolling evaluation of forecast accuracy is [an extremely good idea](https://www.otexts.org/fpp2/accuracy.html).

You can use the [mase](/questions/tagged/mase) or any other accuracy measure like the [mape](/questions/tagged/mape) or [mae](/questions/tagged/mae) to evaluate rolling or non-rolling forecasts - your setup doesn't matter for your choice of evaluation measure.

Indeed, if you look into the academic literature, e.g., the [*International Journal of Forecasting*](https://ijf.forecasters.org/), you will see many examples of rolling evaluations using the MASE or other error measures.

Comment: Do I assume that even though I'm using 12 months to determine a 1 month forecast, the error is based on the full 12 month forecast and not just the one that is not being over-written?  That's what's confusing me.

Comment: That will depend on how you code your error measure. If you use only a single forecast (e.g., only Jan-2017 in the first case), you get an "ASE", no "Mean" involved. But if you then average these single errors over your rolling setup, you again get a MASE. Or you can do "averages of averages", depending on what forecast horizon you are really interested in.